# How to solve the link library problem -lgcc_s

Tags: gcc

I am trying to compile a script with [GCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) on my Ubuntu system and get this error:

```
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether `gcc` is properly installed. If not install using the command

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-x.x
```

replace x.x with the proper version.

If gcc is installed properly then the issue might be with the link. Check whether lgcc_s is properly linked.

libgcc files are located under `/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/x.x`

Comment: i have 4.6 and 4.6.1

Comment: check in 4.6.1 directory

Comment: it has libgcc_s.so

Comment: do i have to do something like  symlink from "/ lib/libgcc.so.1" to "/ lib / libgcc.so

Comment: its in one of the post over the internet

Comment: try this `sudo ln -s /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 /lib/libgcc_s.so`

Comment: it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Use apt-file to find the package with the missing library:

```
$ apt-file search libgcc_s.so
...snip .many packaegs for other architecutes
libgcc-s1: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
...
```

So assuming it's the 64 bit version you want, install the package:

```
sudo apt install libgcc-s1
```